# What is the unit of a "page" in /proc/<pid>/statm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory-usage

According to the linux man pages of proc(5):

> /proc/[pid]/statm
>       Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages. The columns are:
>
> ```
> size       (1) total program size
>            (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)
> resident   (2) resident set size
>            (same as VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status)
> share      (3) shared pages (i.e., backed by a file)
> text       (4) text (code)
> lib        (5) library (unused in Linux 2.6)
> data       (6) data + stack
> dt         (7) dirty pages (unused in Linux 2.6)
> ```

if I compare the results with the ubuntu system monitor the units seem to be Mb, but I'm not 100% sure. What does "measured in pages" means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pagesize is a unit of memory assignment/addressing used by the Linux kernel.

You find out what the size it is (in bytes) with `getconf PAGESIZE`

4096 = 4kB is the default.